# AVCaptureDevice - How to know which application is using it?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, avfoundation

I am using AVCaptureDevice to access the webcam on my MacBook. It has the property
 [inUseByAnotherApplication](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureDevice_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/AVCaptureDevice/inUseByAnotherApplication)  to observe that the device is used by some other application. But how can I know which application is using this AVCaptureDevice. Can anyone please provide me with the solution or some leads.

Comment: But I require the applications that are using this device and not other devices that are linked to it.

Comment: I must've read the question completely wrong my apologies